# Android using VPNService hoggs CPU

Tags: android, vpn

We are using VPNService and conforming to all the methods mentioned in the API spec however recently I figured out that when I am trying to switch network e.g. going to setting --> Wireless & networks-> Mobile Networks --> Preferred Network Type . There I am changing from LTE to 3G.
This gives me jump in VPNService process which I am creating to work for VPN process.

Please could anyone suggest if there is a known limitation to this service or we are missing anything while implementing it.

Thanks in advance!